# Tensorflow cross validation is impossibly high

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I am training tensorflow on a 3 hidden layer network (8 dense nodes in each layer).

```
def build_nn(self, board_dimensions):
    self.model.add(Dense(board_dimensions, activation='relu', input_shape=(board_dimensions,)))
    self.model.add(Dense(board_dimensions, activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(Dense(board_dimensions, activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
    self.model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer="adam")
```

My sample Y outputs are all between 0 and 1

**My input size is dangerously close to my RAM limit.**

I find that when I keep enlarging my sample set, at some point **val_loss: 1.000** .

This is not a gradual change.

I can generate as many training samples as I need
Each simulation session produces several 1000s of input samples

```
Training on samples generated from 20k sessions my val_loss is ~0.37
Training on samples generated from 30k sessions my val_loss is ~0.33
Training on samples generated from 35k sessions my val_loss is ~0.31
Training on samples generated from 40k sessions my val_loss is all of a sudden ~1.00
```

This also very strange, because the mean Y sample value is 0.49, from range (0,1). So even a random guess should give me val_loss of less than 0.5.

Could this be a variance problem? But then why does increasing the sample size damage the predictions?

Is this just tensorflow running out of memory?
Contrary to other cases, I don't see any out of memory errors.

Comment: Are you confirmed that the data is prepared properly? Training and test data are configured correctly ? Looks possible that your input data array is broken ? Also could you include the part of the code that is doing the actual training? Could be a missed parameter there.

Comment: You sound confused. MSE loss is not a *percentage*; a value of, say, 0.56, means 0.56, and *not* 56%. A random guess in a *regression* problem (like yours here) will *not* give you 50% loss - this only holds for the accuracy (not loss) of a (binary) *classification* problem.

Comment: @desertnaut thanks for the clearing up the terminoligy (I edited the question to reflect your comment). Although, correct me if I'm wrong, but if all samples are between 0 and 1, and I have a complete "relu" network, then the likelyhood of getting a val-cost of 1.0 are completely impossible. I would need all of my randomly selected validation set to be 0's or 1's. And I would need the network to consistanttly predict the exact oppisite. Given that the network performs fine with 35k sample sessions, but not with 40k, the chance that this is a statistical error is highly unlikely

Comment: Nope. Recall that ReLU is lower-bounded by 0, but it is not *upper*-bounded; there may be the case that, at that point, your model predicts values well above 1.0. The real issue here is not the exact value of loss (1.0), but why the model performance *suddenly* makes a jump to the worse. You should seriously consider early stopping.